# How is the cgroup pam module configured?

Tags: linux, pam, cgroup

Linux has a PAM module that manipulates cgroups. How is it configured (what options does it support?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings for the module are controlled by `/etc/cgrules.conf` just as for the rest of the cgroup facilities. When added to the PAM stack for a particular program, the program will inherit the cgroup as appropriate for its UID/GID.

If you add the `pam_cgroup` module to the login stack, the user's process will all automatically belong to the user's cgroup when they log in.

The details of this are actually documented in the `README` file for [libcg](http://libcg.sourceforge.net/). Here's a [direct link](http://libcg.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=libcg/libcg;a=blob;f=README;h=54e0f7bb20b16f6b45c2a8f37af22a06d003b7c5;hb=HEAD) to the README in the git repo.

Comment: for services other than login, like su, you can force the PAM module to fire by editing the services file in /etc/pam.d/_service_